# Format of linker map file

Tags: c, gcc

I have generated linker map file from gcc for my C code. Where do I find the format of the .map file so I can exactly figure out what is in there instead of guessing it.

I couldn't find any reference or links in the gcc help.

Comment: It’s a text file, right? Edit the question to add the first 10-20 lines of the file so someone can describe the meaning of the fields without having to run the linker themselves. That stuff is rather common and it’s the sort of “background knowledge” you acquire as you develop software. It’s probably self-explanatory for most people and the manual writer didn’t think it necessary to further describe it. Even though there is a clear need for such a description - not everyone using the linker has had a decade of experience.

Comment: Most likely, it's an implementation detail, which means GCC authors would rather reserve the right to change it as they see fit. It it that hard to understand and parse?

Comment: There's some information in the GNU [`ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) manual.  It is the loader that handles generating map files; you need to find the right manual for the loader on your system.

Comment: The `.map` file is ascii text. It appears to generate much of the information that `readelf -a` generates. So, you may get as much [or more] from `readelf` and/or `objdump` utilities. Or, you could scrape/merge the output of any combo of those three methods.